# How to throw a ball vive controller object in unity3d

Tags: unity, c#, htc-vive

I have this simple line of code that through the ball. Under arm throw is right while if i try through any else ways its through movement is weird like a curve from down to up. what i am doing wrong. how do i through the ball using controller (touchingObject) object direction correctly/realistically.
Additionally i am also encounter a problem that if i through one ball all the previous throw balls move in that direction also. what the heck is that?

```
gameObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody> ().AddForce(touchingObject.transform.forward * 1000);
```

Comment: It would be easier to help if you posted the code you are working with

Comment: hi jon code snippet added

Comment: You are adding a force in relation to the transform.forward vector of your gameobject.  This is completely irrelevant to your throwing motion.  You need to add a force to the object based on your Controller velocity.

Comment: @Jon touchingObject is my controller